# How to populate DevExpress GridControl with Dynamic Objects

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress

I have an endpoint that returns an array of objects. I want to populate a DevExpress GridControl by making the keys of the object the columns and populating the rows with each objects corresponding value. The issue is that the gridcontrol only populates when I explicitly define what the keys of the json object is like this:

```
       foreach(dynamic item in json){
            report.Add(new
            {
                AccountID = item["AccountID"],
                AccountTypeID = item["AccountTypeID"],
                PrefixID = item["PrefixID"],
                SuffixID = item["SuffixID"],
                GenderID = item["GenderID"],
                PrimaryContactID = item["PrimaryContactID"]
            });
        }
```

I don't want to hard code this because the array that is returned from my endpoint has different object structures returned.
This is what I have so far, it gets the properties of my dynamic object and makes them the column names. It works in creating the column names but the rows are all empty.

```
    public GridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();
        PopulateGridView();
    }

    public async void PopulateGridView()
    {
        dynamic json = await model.GetItemAsync();

        var report = new List<object>();
        var custom = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(dynamic item in json){
            report.Add(item);
        }

        grid.ItemsSource = report;

        foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)json[0])
        {
            TextColumn current = new TextColumn();
            current.FieldName = x.Name;
            grid.Columns.Add(current);
        }
    }
```

Here's what that looks like

[image]

Comment: do the grid have a Bind or DataBind method..? or perhaps try moving this `grid.ItemsSource = report;` after you fill the columns..

Comment: @MethodMan damn, I moved the grid.ItemsSource and it still yields the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, what I did was create a DataTable. I took one object from the array and got all its properties to create the data tables column's and then created a function AddRow to add a row to the DataTable and did a foreach on all the objects in the same dynamic manner.

```
    public DataTable dataTable { get; set; }

    public GridView(dynamic obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        PopulateGridView();
    }

    public async void PopulateGridView()
    {
        dynamic json = await model.GetItemAsync();

        if(json == null){
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }

        AddColumns(json[0]);

        foreach (dynamic item in json)
        {
            AddRow(item);
        }

        grid.ItemsSource =  dataTable;

    }

    void AddColumns(dynamic obj)
    {
        foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)obj)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(x.Name, typeof(string));
        }
    }

    void AddRow(dynamic obj)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

        foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)obj)
        {
            row[x.Name] = x.Value;
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all dynamic objects in the sequence have the uniform structure, create a custom collection class implementing the ITypedList interface.

In the [ITypedList.GetItemPropertis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.getitemproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) method, retrieve all available property names from the first object in the collection, and return the collection of custom property descriptors. The custom property descriptor should can read/write a value from/to the dynamic object given a property name.

The Grid will use property descriptors to access values in the dynamic object. This solution will work, since all data bound components natively support ITypedList collections.